# Internal page - don't want it crawled

Tags: php, seo

Please indulge my simplistic example:

Let's say I have 1 million pages on my site.  Each page has an ID number (i.e. www.mysite.com/product.php?id=1 .... upto id=1,000,000

I want to make a page that allows users to email themselves the link to the page (or email a friend).  This page is also dynamic and comes from the product.php, so like this:
www.mysite.com/email_a_friend.php?id=1 .... upto id=1,000,000

Imagine I do this and now google wants to crawl 2 million pages instead of 1 million.  This seems pointless since the page doesn't have anything of any value on the email page.  Also, consider that the email page would actually be a pop-up window on the product.php page.

What is the best way to handle this?

Should I block it (email_a_friend.php) through a robots.txt file?

Or should I perhaps used java or something else for the link that google would ignore anyway?

Thanks!!

Comment: robots.txt is the way to go. You can block a single file or entire directories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you have an e-commerce site and want to implement a share button for a particular product. What you don't want to happen is have google index the page that the share button goes to.

If that's the case, just add a rel="nofollow" to the link in your php that generates the link and you should have no problem.

Here is a google help article that explains how google does not follow links with the nofollow attribute: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=96569

Comment: I get the feeling that nofollow isn't absolute for google.  I just don't want google to even think about the page since there's nothing there that's not on the page it's coming from.  I don't want to dilute my product page or have duplicate content.  I also don't want to worry about how the URL looks.  It's just a page to do a function.  If I had more skills, I'd make an ajax or java popup thingy.

Comment: Nofollow is the standard; if Google choose to ignore it, it's their (and/or their users') problem. Using Javascript just for link obfuscation is evil.

Comment: @tripleee - Evil?  It's the 'users' problem?  Ok, due respect, but that answer seems ridiculous to me.  What if you had a link that users click to vote thumbs up or down; would it be evil' to try to ensure that googlebot doesn't repeatedly click it, voting both up/down for everything it crawls?  I'm just trying to make the site function correctly.  Plus, if nofollow is 'standard', then why is there 'robots.txt'?

Comment: @Kevin I added some documentation from google that explicitly says they do not follow links with the nofollow attribute placed.

Comment: The same standard specifies `robots.txt` behavior and `nofollow` links. They serve related purposes, but different scenarios. Having said that, if you want to protect against evil and/or amateur bots, too, the standards obviously won't help.